# How can I read the value of a ViewState into a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I have a dictionary declared in the field such as:

```
Dictionary<String, string[]> operationDetails = new Dictionary<string, string[]> { };
```

Some operations are carried out and the dictionary is stored back into a ViewState like so:

```
ViewState.Add("operationDetails", operationDetails);
```

I now want to read this variable and store it back into `operationDetails`:

```
operationDetails = ViewState["operationDetails"];
```

However, this returns me with the error of unable to convert object to dictionary. I have tried `Convert.ToDictionary` but such a statement does not exist.

How can I read this view state back into a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the ViewState back to it's original DataType

```
operationDetails = ViewState["operationDetails"] as Dictionary<String, string[]>;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is why it is suggested to use **ViewBag** instead of *ViewState*
it save you from the re-conversion in the view

```
set in c#   as  ViewBag.operationDetails = operationDetails;
get in razor as operationDetails =ViewBag.operationDetails
```